# Can Blender 2.9+ mimic the Blender 2.8 Outliner functionality to enter Edit Mode on any object in a single click?

Tags: outliner

In 2.83 it was just a single left click on the mesh like this, even coming from Pose Mode:

[image: Pose Mode to Edit Mode in one left click in the Outliner]

Since 2.83 LTS is going out of support, I want to upgrade to 2.93 LTS or higher. But not if it means working slower. And it looks like all versions from 2.9+ lost this functionality. I would be willing to install any addons that could help, thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still switch between objects in *Edit Mode* as shown below. But it looks like it's not possible to switch from *Edit Mode* or *Pose Mode* of non-mesh obejcts. It seems that the fastest way to switch from *Pose Mode* is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> which switches Armature back to *Object Mode*. Then you can select the a mesh-based object and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* again. So unfortunately a bit more manual.

[image]

Comment: Is there any fast way to switch from Pose Mode on an Armature to Edit Mode on a mesh any more? In 2.9+ it seems way slower, needing to manually switch to Object Mode, then select the other object in Object Mode, then tab into Edit Mode, and switching back to Pose Mode is even worse because you can't just tab into Pose Mode. And that needs to be repeated, every single time you are moving from posing to editing?

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I know there seems to be none except for doing `Ctrl+tab` to switch back to object mode of armature then click on mesh object and press `tab` :(